# Bitmap page allocator in C

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-optimization, kernel

Bitmap page allocator that scans the bitmap linearly looking for `size` amount of pages. Everytime it founds a free page, it check if the next `size` pages are also free, if yes it  marks them as allocated and returns a pointer to the first page

````
uint64_t *bitmap;

#define setpage(p, x) bitmap[p / 64] = x << (p % 64) | bitmap[p / 64]
#define getpage(p) bitmap[p / 64] & ((1 << (p % 64)))

void *palloc(int size) {
    struct limine_hhdm_response *hhdm_res = hhdm_req.response;
    int page = PGSIZE, p = 0;
    while (1) {

        // if free 
        if ((getpage(page)) == 0) {

            // check that there are 'size' amount of pages free 
            for (p = page; p < (size + page); ++p) {
                if ((getpage(p)) == 1)
                    break;
            }

            // mark the pages as used
            if (p == size + page) {
                for (p = page; p < (size + page); ++p) 
                    setpage(p, 1);
                return (void*) hhdm_res + (page * PGSIZE);
            }
        };
        page++;
    };
}   
```
````

Answer (score 5):

There are several issues with this code:

- Avoid macros where possible: `setpage()` and `getpage()` can easily be implemented as regular functions. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104568/macro-vs-function-in-c) for an overview of the issues with macros.
- Buffer overflows: you never check if you are accessing past the end of the bitmap. If you are out of memory, or even if you have enough memory but it is so fragmented you can't find a large enough bit of contiguous free space, you will read and write past the end of `bitmap[]` and probably return a pointer to memory which doesn't exist or is already in use by something else.
- It can be made more efficient: checking the bitmap bit for bit is slow for large allocations. There are several ways to check many bits at a time. For example, if a given `uint64_t` is 0, you know that block of 64 pages is completely free, and if it is `UINT64_MAX`, you know every page in that block is in use. You also have functions like [`ffs()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ffs.3.html) that allow you to find the first non-zero bit in one go (or you can write your own using compiler [builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), intrinsics or inline assembly).
- If you have a lot of pages, linearly scanning the bitmap can become a bottleneck for allocations.
- The cast in the `return` statement is not necessary.

Comment: why avoid macros?

Comment: I added a link to my answer to another post discussing macros vs. functions. In short, there are several issues with macros that make mistakes easy, and they are harder to debug.